# While inserting String value (java) in Enum field (DB) Getting " Data truncated for column"

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

In my mysql table there is one enum field 'spe_gender'.

```
mysql> desc tbl_sswltdata_persons;
+-----------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| spe_id          | bigint(20) unsigned   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| spe_sen_id      | bigint(20) unsigned   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| spe_gender      | enum('male','female') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| spe_is_deceased | tinyint(1)            | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| spe_birth_place | varchar(255)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| spe_create_date | datetime              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| spe_update_date | datetime              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So I created one POJO class as:

```
public class SswltdataPersons implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long spe_id;
    private long spe_sen_id;
    private String spe_gender;
    private String spe_is_deceased;
    private String spe_birth_place;
    private String spe_create_date;
    private String spe_update_date;

    // .........

    public String getSpe_gender() {
        return spe_gender;
    }
    public void setSpe_gender(String spe_gender) {
        this.spe_gender = spe_gender;
    }

    // ......

}
```

When I trying to write data into this table I am getting an exception

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL 
    [INSERT INTO iwpro_imp.tbl_sswltdata_persons VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; 
    Data truncated for column 'spe_gender' at row 1; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncated for column 'spe_gender' at row 1
```

I think the issue is While inserting String value (through java) in Enum field (in DB). Here is my methods where I am getting Exception.

```
@Transactional(value="transactionManager_iwpro_imp", rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void saveAllPersons(final List<SswltdataPersons> list) {


        String sql = "INSERT INTO iwpro_imp.tbl_sswltdata_persons VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        try{
            jdbcTemplate.update("SET foreign_key_checks = 0");

            List<List<SswltdataPersons>> batchLists = Lists.partition(list, batchSize);

            for(final List<SswltdataPersons> batch : batchLists) {
                BatchPreparedStatementSetter bpss = new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                    @Override
                    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int index) throws SQLException {
                        SswltdataPersons dataObject = batch.get(index);
                        ps.setLong(1, dataObject.getSpe_id());
                        ps.setLong(2, dataObject.getSpe_sen_id());
                        ps.setString(3, dataObject.getSpe_gender());
                        ps.setString(4, dataObject.getSpe_is_deceased());
                        ps.setString(5, dataObject.getSpe_birth_place());
                        ps.setString(6, dataObject.getSpe_create_date());
                        ps.setString(7, dataObject.getSpe_update_date());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getBatchSize() {
                        return batch.size();
                    }
                };
                jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, bpss);
            }

            jdbcTemplate.update("SET foreign_key_checks = 1");

        }catch(Exception e){
            TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
            logger.error("\n\nUnexpected Exception:\n", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Can't I insert this enum value in DB?

Comment: You should use an explicit column list in the `INSERT` statement to make sure that your variables get bound to the correct column. What data do you have in `dataObject`?

Comment: You should first check that your enum value java-side is really 'male' or 'female', and you should specify column names in the insert query to be sure each value will be stored in the correct column

Comment: Actually I am copying the data from one server to another server (both databases are identical). so dataObject contains data from server 1 which I am going to write on server 2. on server 2 I am getting exception.

Comment: @MickMnemonic still I am getting the same error after changing the query to :    String sql = "INSERT INTO iwpro_imp.tbl_sswltdata_persons (spe_id, spe_sen_id, spe_gender, spe_is_deceased, spe_birth_place, spe_create_date, spe_update_date) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

Comment: What is the value of `dataObject.getSpe_gender()` ?

Comment: System.out.println(dataObject.getSpe_gender()); clearly prints male and female. nothing else

Comment: Are you sure that the data doesn't contain whitespace?

Comment: As null value is allowed in DB, I am getting 3 types of values. System.out.println(dataObject.getSpe_gender() + " ::: " + dataObject.getSpe_gender().length()); is giving me female ::: 6
male ::: 4
 ::: 0

Comment: .length() would not work with null (would give a NullPointerException), you're inserting an empty string there.

Comment: Maybe try `ps.setString(3, dataObject.getSpe_gender().isEmpty() ? null : dataObject.getSpe_gender());`?

Comment: that worked. :) thanks @MickMnemonic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mick Mnemonic for the suggestion. It worked.

replacing

```
ps.setString(3, dataObject.getSpe_gender().isEmpty());
```

with

```
ps.setString(3, dataObject.getSpe_gender().isEmpty() ? null : dataObject.getSpe_gender());
```

worked for me. Thanks all.

Comment: Shouldn't the value to set 
be `null` instead of `""` when the enum value is empty?

Comment: yup. answer modified.

Answer (score 0):

In your java code, declare spe_gender as an Enum type

```
private Gender spe_gender
```

where Gender is an Enum class

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE,
    FEMALE
}
```

Comment: If I change it to type Gender, then how I will write ps.setString(3, dataObject.getSpe_gender()); as setString accepts only (int, String)

Comment: in this case you would have to convert it to string, and in your case, to lower case as well, so it would be something like: `dataObject.getSpe_gender().name.toLowerCase()`, or simply add a method to the enum that returns the name in lower case

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer that, you would have to give an example of the data actually being inserted.

Anyway, regarding the exception that you get, you're most likely not inserting "male" or "female", since it says "Data truncated for column 'spe_gender' at row 1" it means that the data you're inserting differs, and is in fact bigger (as in more characters) than the allowed one.

<strike>Also, check if there's an actual method to insert enums rather than "setString".</strike> -> EDIT: it does not

Comment: I printed out the data and I think I am inserting the right values. See here the SOP result:   System.out.println(dataObject.getSpe_gender() + " ::: " + dataObject.getSpe_gender().length()); is giving me female ::: 6 male ::: 4 ::: 0

Comment: Like I said in the comments, you're inserting an empty string, try @mick-mnemonic suggestion, should work

Comment: replacing ps.setString(3, dataObject.getSpe_gender().isEmpty());
with 
ps.setString(3, dataObject.getSpe_gender().isEmpty() ? "" : dataObject.getSpe_gender());

worked for me.

Comment: That should actually not work, giving it an empty string would give the same error as before, it should be `null`

Comment: yup its null. that's typo.
ps.setString(3, dataObject.getSpe_gender().isEmpty() ? null : dataObject.getSpe_gender());